# Take a snapshot of a html page using Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am working on a RoR project which have a table with a lot of link images. These images are snapshots of the linked page. The linked pages changes several times a day so it must be updated often.

Any ideas of how I can achieve that?

I think that I can have a process to generate the snapshots but it should be uploaded to Heroku in the future. 
I prefer a solution that is integrated with my solution (i.e. a rake task).

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, I need an small image (like 40px x 40px) of the content of the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [IMGKit](https://github.com/csquared/IMGKit) to generate image and then ImageMagick or something else to resize an image

Comment: Any hint how you did it @Tony ?

Comment: I followed the tutorial in IMGKit github. It worked pretty well.